# How to get the watches Battery in WatchKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit

So theres no public way to get the battery level in watchKit that I've found.

So there's no `UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel` and `WKInterfaceDevice` doesn't seam to have the goods.

In LLDB, importing UIKit and WatchKit, I'm able to get back

```
(lldb) e (Class) NSClassFromString(@"UIDevice")
(Class) $0 = 0x3756bfa0
(lldb) e (id) [$0 currentDevice]
(id) $1 = 0x16d83860
(lldb) e (float)[(id) [$0 currentDevice] batteryLevel]
(float) $2 = -1
```

Obv. I'm ok with solutions that utilize private api for this project. Also, maybe its available somehow through iOS? Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the battery level on the watch like this:

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
let batteryLevel = WKInterfaceDevice.current().batteryLevel
```

Comment: Please Note that if you dont specify the first line, i.e if you dont set isBatterMonitoringEnabled then the batteryLevel will be -1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Public API to access the Apple Watch battery level was made available from **WatchOS 4.x**:

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().batteryLevel
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/2868462-batterylevel

Comment: as I'm open to solutions that utilize nonpublic api, this response doesn't demonstrate that its not possible.

Comment: I've never seen a way to do it in the wild. Given Apple controls the hardware and the software, and they only publish a public API without any battery access properties or methods, it's probably extremely hard to do if it's even possible.

Comment: You might want to file a bug report if you have a legitimate use case and want to see if Apple will respond